# how to detect a mouse click on drawn image?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# Windows Form Application Development.

I created a form with a panel in which the user can draw image on it. How do I check if the image is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

In designer mode, right-click on the panel, go to Properties.
In the Properties window, choose EVENTS (Lightning icon).
Double click on Click, then this code will be generated:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //--what to do when user clicks on panel--
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
    }
```

Comment: thanks,but here i am drawing an image on the panel,now if i made a mouse click ,how to detect if it was on the image or not(i mean if the click was done on the image or on the rest portion of the panel)help me futher atleast suggestion or any  hint

Comment: what type of image can a user draw?

Comment: iam drawing a png image on apanel ,now i want to check for a mouse click only on the image

Answer (score 2):

Just double-click on the form's image-panel (or whatever object you wish to detect click events on) and Visual Studio will automatically generate a `OnClick()` event. Needless to say, I'm talking about the forms designer, not the actual form you will see when testing your code.

Alternatively, you can set which events you want to implement through the object's properties. That way you can also implement `OnKeyDown()` or `OnFocus()` or any other kind of events.

**Edit:** If the image doesn't cover the entire panel, you'll have to check if the mouse position is within the image's dimension. Assuming the image is drawn at position `(imgOriginX, imgOriginY)` and has the size `(imgWidth, imgHeight)`:

```
// Fires, when user clicks on panel
private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cast to MouseEventArgs
    MouseEventArgs mouse = (MouseEventArgs)e;

    // If mouse is within image
    if (mouse.X >= imgOriginX && mouse.Y >= imgOriginY && mouse.X < imgOriginX + imgWidth && mouse.Y < imgOriginY + imgHeight)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,but here i am drawing an image on the panel,now if i made a mouse click ,how to detect if it was on the image or not(i mean if the click was done on the image or on the rest portion of the panel)help me futher atleast suggestion or any hint

Comment: @user2074911 So the image doesn't cover the entire panel? In that case, how about seeing if the mouse position is within the image's dimension? Assuming the image is drawn at position (20,10) and has the size (200,100); `if (e.X >= 20 && e.Y >= 10 && e.X < 20 + 200 && e.Y < 10 + 100)`.